# Cannot get route

Tags: express

I am trying to create my first express app, however I already have some issues. I am not able to access my routes. I keep getting error `Cannot GET /api/test` whenever I route to `/api/test` - What am  I doing wrong?

routes/testRoute.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { getTest } = require('../controllers/testRouteController');

router.get('/test', getTest);

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hi' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/testRouteController.js

```js
const getTest = (req, res) => {
  console.log('Hello');
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'base' });
};

module.exports = {
  getTest,
};
```

index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3010 || 5000;

const testRoute = require('./routes/testRoute');

app.get('/api', testRoute);

app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mount routers using `app.use()`:

```
app.use('/api', testRoute);
```